# PostGIS : improving the speed of query over complex geometry

Tags: postgis, query-performance

I am new to PostgreSQL and PostGIS but the question is not trivial.  I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 with PostGIS 2.2.

I need to run some queries that take a horrible amount of time.

**First, let me explain the problem in non-GIS terms :**
Basically, I have a set of several hundreds of thousands of points spread over a territory of about half a million square kilometres a (country).
Over this territory, I have about a dozen sets of areas coming from various databases. In each set, I have between a few hundreds and a few thousands of areas. I want to find which points are in any of these areas.

**Now, how I am currently working out the problem in GIS terms :**

Each set of areas is a Postgresql table with a geometry column of the type *multipolygon* and with, as explained before a few hundreds to a few thousand records.
All these tables are contained in a schema *donnees* but I am using a different schema for these operations, called *traitements*.

So the process is a/ merging all the geometries into a single geometry, and then b/ finding which points are contained in this geometry.

The problem is that, if step a/ took a reasonable amount of time (several minutes), step b/ takes forever. 
I am currently working with only a sample of the points I must process (about 1% of them, i.e. about 7000) and it is not finished after several hours (the database connection eventually times out).
I am making tests running the query by limiting the number of return rows to 10 or 50 and it still takes about half an hour for that.
I am using a Linux Mint 18 machine with 4 CPU and 8 Gb of RAM if you wonder.

I have created indexes on the geometry columns. All geometry columns use the same SRID.

**Creating the tables :**

```
CREATE TABLE traitements.sites_candidats (
    pkid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    statut varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    geom geometry(Point, 2154)
); 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON traitements.sites_candidats (origine, origine_id ) ;
CREATE INDEX ON traitements.sites_candidats (statut);
CREATE INDEX sites_candidats_geométrie ON traitements.sites_candidats USING GIST ( geom );

CREATE TABLE  traitements.zones_traitements (
    pkid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    définition varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    geom geometry (MultiPolygon, 2154)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON traitements.zones_traitements (définition) ;
CREATE INDEX zones_traitements_geométrie ON traitements.zones_traitements USING GIST ( geom );
```

Please note that I specified the geometry type of the *geom* column in table *traitements* only because I wanted to specify the SRID but I was not sure what is the correct syntax for any type of Geometry. Maybe "geom geometry (Geometry, 2154)" ?

**Merging all the geometries of the various sets of areas :**
As said before, all the tables hold geometries of the type multipolygon.
This is the code I am using to merge all the geometries from one of the tables :

```
INSERT INTO traitements.zones_traitements
    ( définition,  , geom )
    VALUES
    (
        'first-level merge', 
        (
            SELECT ST_Multi(ST_Collect(dumpedGeometries)) AS singleMultiGeometry 
            FROM
            (
                SELECT ST_Force2D((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) AS dumpedGeometries
                FROM donnees.one_table
            ) AS dumpingGeometries
        )
    ) ;
```

I found that some of the geometries in some of the records are in 3D, so that's why I am using _ST_Force2D_.

I do this for all the tables and then merge the geometries again using :

```
INSERT INTO traitements.zones_traitements
    ( définition, geom )
    VALUES
    (
        'second-level merge',
        (
            SELECT ST_Multi(ST_Collect(dumpedGeometries)) AS singleMultiGeometry 
            FROM
            (
                SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom AS dumpedGeometries 
                FROM traitements.zones_traitements
                WHERE définition != 'second-level merge'
            ) AS dumpingGeometries
        )
    ) ;
```

As said before, these queries take several minutes but that's fine.

Not the query that takes forever :

```
SELECT pkid
    FROM traitements.sites_candidats AS sites
    JOIN (
        SELECT geom FROM traitements.zones_traitements 
        WHERE définition = 'zones_rédhibitoires' ) AS zones
    ON ST_Contains(zones.geom , sites.geom)
    LIMIT 50;
```

**Analysing the problem :**
Obviously, it is the subquery selecting the points that takes a lot of time, not the update.
So I have run an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) on the query :

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
    SELECT pkid
    FROM traitements.sites_candidats AS sites
    JOIN (
        SELECT geom FROM traitements.zones_traitements 
        WHERE définition = 'second_level_merge' ) AS zones
    ON ST_Contains(zones.geom , sites.geom)
    LIMIT 10;

---------------------------------

"Limit  (cost=4.18..20.23 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=6052.069..4393634.244 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=688784"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.18..20.23 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=6052.068..4391938.803 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=688784"
"        ->  Seq Scan on zones_traitements  (cost=0.00..1.23 rows=1 width=54939392) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              Filter: (("définition")::text = 'zones_rédhibitoires'::text)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 17"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sites_candidats sites  (cost=4.18..19.00 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=6052.044..4391260.053 rows=10 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: (zones_traitements.geom ~ geom)"
"              Filter: _st_contains(zones_traitements.geom, geom)"
"              Heap Blocks: exact=1"
"              Buffers: shared read=688784"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "sites_candidats_geométrie"  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=23.284..23.284 rows=3720 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (zones_traitements.geom ~ geom)"
"                    Buffers: shared read=51"
"Planning time: 91.967 ms"
"Execution time: 4399271.394 ms"
```

I am not sure how to read this output.

Nevertheless, I suspect that the query is so slow because of the geometry obtained by merging all these multipolygons into a single one.

**Questions :**
Would that work better using a different type of geometry to merge the others, like a *GeometryCollection* ?
How does the indexes work in this case ?

Is there more efficient than ST_Contains() ?

Comment: I already found out that some of the geometries are not valid in the first place. I am trying to filter the invalid geometries and see if it improves the result.

Answer (score 2):

Let´s see. First off, you should ask GIS specific questions over at [GIS Stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/). But I´ll try to help here:

- Technically, your geometry column definition is correct, and using
  'primitives' (e.g. *POINT, LINE, POLYGON* and their *MULTI*s) is favorable
  over *GEOMETRYCOLLECTION*s.
  However, it is almost always the better
  choice to run spatial relation functions on as small a geometry as
  possible; for most of those functions, PostGIS has to check **each and
  every vertice** of the input geometries against each other (so in this
  case, it has to traverse the polygon's millions of vertices once for each point
  to be checked in `ST_Contains`).
  PostGIS will in fact fire up a bbox
  comparison prior to the relation checks (if an index is present on
  both geometries) to limit the possible matches and effectively
  speeding up the check by several magnitudes; this is rendered useless
  here.
  (I would almost recommend to actually dump the *MULTI*s into simple *POLYGONS*, but not without knowing your data).
- Why are you dumping the *MULTI* geometries just to collect them
  back into *MULTI*s? If your source table's geometries are actually stored as *MULTIPOLYGONS* (and hopefully for good reason), simply copy them into the intermediate table, with `ST_Force2D` used on the *MULTI*s and `ST_IsValid` in the `WHERE` block (you can try `ST_MakeValid`on the geometries, but there's no guarantee it will work).
  If you have inserted all tables into the *zones_traitements* table, run `VACUUM ANALYZE` and `REINDEX` to actually make use of the index!
- In your 'second merge' query...are you simply adding the 'merged' geometries to the existing ones in the table? Don´t, that´s just wrong. It messes up table statistics and the index and is quite the unnecessary overhead. You should do these things within your query, but it´s not necessary here.
- Keep in mind that geometries of different types or extends **created or derived by or within queries** can neither have an index nor use the initial one. This applies to your 'merging' queries!

Then run

```
SELECT pkid
FROM traitements.sites_candidats AS sites
JOIN traitements.zones_traitements AS zones
  ON ST_Intersects(zones.geom, sites.geom)
```

to return one *pkid* for every intersection with a *zone* so that if one point intersects two *MULTIOLYGON*s, you´ll get two rows for that point. Use `SELECT DISTINCT pkid ...` to only get one row per *pkid* that is intersecting any *zone*.
(Note: I used `ST_Intersection` because that should imply on less check on the relation. If you absolutely need `ST_Contains`, just replace it)
Hope this helps. If not, say a word.

Comment: Hi. I did not know about GIS StackExchange. Thanks ! It is indeed where I should have posted this question.

Comment: @DarthKangaroo jep, best place on the web for anything GIS. come join us there!

Answer (score 1):

Again, thanks.

I had come to the same conclusion as your advice : that, instead of merging all the thousands of multipolygons into a single huge one, whose bbox is too huge,  it would be more efficient to decompose all the multipolygons into simple polygons using ST_Dump and insert these into a dedicated table with an appropriate index. 
Nevertheless, to do this, I first had to correct geometries : certain multipolygons had indeed unvalid geometries. St_MakeValid would make valid 90% of them as multipolygons but the rest was transformed into either GeometryCollections or MultilineStrings. To correct these, I used ST_Buffer, with a buffer of 0.01 meter, the result of which being a correct multipolygon.
Once this was done, all my multipolygons were valid and I could dump them into simple polygons.

Doing this, I reduced the search time by a factor of +/- 5000 !

:D

Comment: nice! glad that worked. did all queries run with expected results?